# Teamcity and clearcase project spanning multiple vobs

Tags: teamcity, clearcase, vob

I have a clearcase project spanning multiple vobs. Teamcity 5.0 appears to assume your project is on a single clearcase vob.

Is it possible to have Teamcity build a clearcase project spanning multiple vobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5252007;jsessionid=4180962E47589E3095358B73539C23BF) seems to suggest a different approach for a multi-vob configuration:

> Now "Relative Path within the view" field is not allowed to be the root. You should specify at least the VOB name.
>
> But you can create two VCS roots for you configuration:
>
> - VCS Root 1:

```
ClearCase View Path: "<SnapRoot path>"
Relative Path Within The View : "Vob 1"
```

> - VCS Root 2:

```
ClearCase View Path: "<SnapRoot path>"
Relative Path Within The View : "Vob 2"
```

> add a checkout rule `"+:.=>Vob 1"` to the first VCS root and a checkout rule `"+:.=>Vob 2"` to the second.

Note: I would try using dynamic views instead of snapshot views, minimizing the "update snapshot views" times.